# In Azure API for VM, is there a way to define many existing data disks with one method?

Tags: c#, azure, fluent, azure-sdk-.net

I have a block of fluent C# code:

If I knew how many disks existed the syntax would be:

```
    var tempVM = await azure.VirtualMachines.Define(targetVMName)
        .WithRegion(vm.Region)
        .WithExistingResourceGroup(targetResourceGroupName)
        .WithNewPrimaryNetworkInterface(nicDefinitions[0])
        .WithSpecializedOSDisk(disks[0], disks[0].OSType.Value)
        .WithSize(vm.Size)
        .WithTags(tags)
        .WithExistingDataDisk(d[0]) <<<<<<<
        .WithExistingDataDisk(d[1]) <<<<<<<
        .WithExistingDataDisk(d[2]) <<<<<<<
        .WithExistingDataDisk(d[3]) <<<<<<<
        .CreateAsync();
```

I may have 0 or more datadisks to add. Is there a fluent syntax to support 0 or more disks ?

Comment: It depends on the library. What library are you using for Azure?

Comment: Perhaps a redesign to have data disks as a separate entity on a 0 to many relationship

Comment: @Robert I actually thought he wrote that himself. My Bad.

Comment: `Is there a fluent syntax to support 0 or more disks ?` -- [There doesn't appear to be.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.compute.fluent.virtualmachine.definition.iwithmanageddatadisk.withexistingdatadisk?view=azure-dotnet)

Comment: Fluent APIs aren't magic, nor a "good" practice by themselves. Sometimes they help, sometimes they make debugging a pain. In many cases, they are just extension methods that return the original interface. You can *easily* create your own extension method that adds an `IEnumerable<>` of disks to the definition and returns it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this is using extension method on an interface named `IWithManagedCreate`, you have this method:

```
public static IWithManagedCreate WithExistingDataDisk(this IWithManagedCreate vm, IDisk disk)
{
    // ...      
    return vm; 
}
```

You could simply add an extension method of your own with a `params IDisk[]` overload:

```
public static IWithManagedCreate WithExistingDataDisks(this IWithManagedCreate vm, params IDisk[] disks)
{
    foreach (var disk in disks)
    {
        vm = vm.WithExistingDataDisk(disk);
    }
    return vm; 
}
```

And call it like that:

```
    .WithTags(tags)
    .WithExistingDataDisks(d) // passing the array containing 0 or more disks
    .CreateAsync();
```

So, to answer the question, no, fluent syntax is nothing special, just a chain of method calls. When you chain method calls (by letting each method return something that you can call more methods on), you can't make them conditional; you can make a method however do nothing as demonstrated above. When you call it with an empty array, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

The `WithExistingDataDisk` is declared in the [`IWithManagedDataDisk`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.compute.fluent.virtualmachine.update.iwithmanageddatadisk?view=azure-dotnet) interface.

This interface doesn't provide any method to add many existing `IDisk` in one call.

Anyway, you can implement it as an extension method like this :

```
public static class WithManagedDataDiskExtensions
{
    // allow to manually specify many disks to add
    public static IWithManagedDataDisk WithExistingDataDisks(this IWithManagedDataDisk self, params IDisk[] disks)
    {
        return self.WithExistingDataDisks((IEnumerable<IDisk>) disks);
    }

    // allow to add an enumerable of many disks
    public static IWithManagedDataDisk WithExistingDataDisks(this IWithManagedDataDisk self, IEnumerable<IDisk> disks)
    {
        foreach (var disk in disks)
            self = self.WithExistingDataDisk(disk);

        return self;
    }
}
```

and use it like that:

```
var tempVM = await azure.VirtualMachines.Define(targetVMName)
    .WithRegion(vm.Region)
    .WithExistingResourceGroup(targetResourceGroupName)
    .WithNewPrimaryNetworkInterface(nicDefinitions[0])
    .WithSpecializedOSDisk(disks[0], disks[0].OSType.Value)
    .WithSize(vm.Size)
    .WithTags(tags)
    .WithExistingDataDisks(d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3])
  //.WithExistingDataDisks(d)
    .CreateAsync();
```

Comment: You could use an `IEnumerable<IDisk>` instead of `params IDisk[]` and pass `d` directly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, d is not necessarily an array, the best option is to have both extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Often in fluent API's you can use an assignment in a loop, like this:

```
   var expTempVM = azure.VirtualMachines.Define(targetVMName)
        .WithRegion(vm.Region)
        .WithExistingResourceGroup(targetResourceGroupName)
        .WithNewPrimaryNetworkInterface(nicDefinitions[0])
        .WithSpecializedOSDisk(disks[0], disks[0].OSType.Value)
        .WithSize(vm.Size)
        .WithTags(tags);

    foreach (var d in disks)
    {
      expTempVM = expTempVM.WithExistingDataDisk(d);
    }

    var tempVM = await expTempVM.CreateAsync();
```

As the basic design of a fluent API is that each method returns the same type that it operates on.

And if you can do that, you can also define your own extension method, `.WithExistingDataDisks` or similar.

Comment: Yeah but `WithTags()` may return a type unassignable from the type returned by `WithExistingDataDisk()` or `CreateAsync()`, so you may need more intermediate variables to store the results in, and putting control flow within a fluent block is kind of beating the purpose to have fluent syntax in the first place...